# xlPasteValue with Copy Destination

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the values in Source Column "H", rather than the formulas.

```vb
With Sheets("Sheet")
    With .Range("H8", .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">0"
        If .SpecialCells(xlVisible).Count > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Register").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

I tried attaching `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` to the end of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make it two lines:

```
With Sheets("Sheet")
    With .Range("H8", .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">0"
        If .SpecialCells(xlVisible).Count > 1 Then
             .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy
             Sheets("Register").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
     End With
     .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```